# UNION ALL / UNION on Presto

Tags: sql, bigdata, union, presto, treasure-data

I am using treasure data for data analytics and having trouble with union statement in presto db.

How do i do a Union All on presto. I dont understand the documentation. everytime I try to do UNION like so:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS ReservationsCreated,
  resource
FROM
  reservation
WHERE
  type = 'create'
UNION
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS ReservationsDeleted,
  resource
FROM
  reservation
WHERE
  type = 'delete'
GROUP BY
  resource
;
```

I get output reformatted like:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS ReservationsCreated,
  resource
FROM
  reservation
WHERE
  type = 'create'
UNION
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS ReservationsDeleted,
resource
FROM
reservation
WHERE
type = 'delete'
GROUP BY
resource
;
```

and error that says:

```
'"resource"' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
```

I think I am not understanding the syntax for Presto. The docs are very confusing on Union. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag because the question is explicitly about prestodb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first part of the query is missing a `group by` as the error says.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ReservationsCreated, resource
 FROM reservation
 WHERE type = 'create'
 group by resource
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ReservationsDeleted, resource
 FROM reservation
 WHERE type = 'delete'
 GROUP BY resource
```

In fact, the query could be simplified to use conditional aggregation.

```
select 
 resource
,sum(case when type = 'create' then 1 else 0 end) as reservationscreated
,sum(case when type = 'delete' then 1 else 0 end) as reservationsdeleted
from reservation
group by resource
```

Comment: I am trying to have a ReservationsCreated and another ResearvationsDeleted columns. If I add the GROUP BY the result sets get combined into the ReservationsCreated and there is no ResearvationsDeleted column in the result

Comment: exactly. the conditional aggregation part of the answer should get you what you need, as separate columns.